# LINQ group by and filter particular record

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { set; get; }
}

List<Data> dta = new List<Data>
{
    new Data { Id =1 , Status ="Open"},
    new Data { Id =1 , Status ="Pending"},
    new Data { Id =2 , Status ="Open"},
    new Data { Id =3 , Status ="Open"},
};
```

Tried so far

```
var outPutData = dta.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == "Pending"));
```

I got a result like below in `outPutData` collection

```
Id =1 , Status ="Pending"
null
null
```

Expected result in outPutData collection

```
Id =1 , Status ="Pending"
Id =2 , Status ="Open"
Id =3 , Status ="Open"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the first item of the group, you can use this:

```
var outPutData = dta
.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
.Select(g =>
{
    return g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == "Pending") ?? g.FirstOrDefault();
});
```

This means that if the current group contains an item with the status Pending, it will return this item. If it doesn't contain an item with the status Pending, `g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == "Pending")` will be null. So `g.FirstOrDefault()` (the first item of the group, or null if none) will be returned.

Comment: thank you #uodami it's useful and clear my thought

Answer (score 2):

Your current Id=2 and Id=3 objects do not have a status of Pending; there are no such objects, so the result of the FirstOrDefault is "default" ie null - FirstOrDefault means "give me the first object in potentially many, where this condition is true, or if there is no matching object, give me the default for the type (null, usually)"

Perhaps instead you want something like

```
var outPutData = dta.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Status == "Pending"?0:1).First());
```

This will rank (order) objects that are Pending so that they come before any objects that are Open and hence will be picked First, but critically it doesn't throw anything away so the Open objects are still available.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this

```
var outPutData = dta
                .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                .Select(g =>
                {
                    Data res;
                    var pending = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == "Pending");
                    if (pending != null)
                    {
                        res = pending;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var other = g.FirstOrDefault();
                        res = other;
                    }
                    return res;
                });
```

Comment: Generally, the OP and future visitors will benefit from answers that have some explanation, rather than "try this [block of code]" - aim to educate, rather than freelance gratis